# Listview, scrollToItem does not work properly in android in appcelerator

Tags: android, listview, scroll, appcelerator

I am trying to implement a screen in Appcelerator, where there are tabs in one view and the other view contains a listview with list sections. On the click of every tab, the respective section and section heading should scroll up. Say, I click on the third widget, the third list section and its section heading should scroll up. I have used the scrollToItem property for this. It works fine on iOS, but doesn't align properly when executing on the android devices. Any suggestions?

Comment: please provide some more info on how you are implementing it in code.. some code snippet would be faster to help you

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in **Android 4.x**, this method would not scroll to correct position when you are running the app on Android 4.x. You can have a look at the Appcelerator docs : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView-method-scrollToItem

So if it is an appcelerator bug then, thumbs down we will need to look for some other options or work around to solve the problem (Maybe a Widget or Module if you want to go specifically with the `listView`).

Or else, you could use the `TableView`, as it also has a method `scrollToIndex`, only thing you cannot add animation in android in this.

**Good Luck & Cheers**